# changing anonymous classes into normal classes in java

Tags: java

I have an anonymous inner class used in Java to be implemented in several other functions, I have tried changing it into a normal class so it can be easier to be converted in c++
This the code i have,

```
interface CombineFunction { 
  void combine(int[] target, int[] source); 
 } 

 class CombineLocals { 
  public int[] Vector; 
  public int[] SrcVector; 
 } 

 void Combine(final BinaryMap source, final RectangleC area, final Point at, 
   final CombineFunction function) { 
  final int shift = (area.X & WordMask) - (at.X & WordMask); 
  int vectorSize = (area.Width >> WordShift) + 2; 
  CombineLocals combineLocals = new CombineLocals(); 
  combineLocals.Vector = new int[vectorSize]; 
  combineLocals.SrcVector = new int[vectorSize]; 
  ParallelForDelegate<CombineLocals> delegate = new ParallelForDelegate<CombineLocals>() { 
   @Override 
   public CombineLocals delegate(int y, CombineLocals locals) { 
    LoadLine(locals.Vector, new Point(at.X, at.Y + y), area.Width); 
    source.LoadLine(locals.SrcVector, 
      new Point(area.X, area.Y + y), area.Width); 
    if (shift >= 0) 
     ShiftLeft(locals.SrcVector, shift); 
    else 
     ShiftRight(locals.SrcVector, -shift); 
    function.combine(locals.Vector, locals.SrcVector); 
    SaveLine(locals.Vector, new Point(at.X, at.Y + y), area.Width); 
    return locals; 
   } 

   @Override 
   public CombineLocals combineResults(CombineLocals result1, 
     CombineLocals result2) { 
    return null; 
   } 
  }; 

  Parallel.For(0, area.Height, delegate, combineLocals); 
 }
```

As the code given above ParallelForDelegate is also another interface that is used like an anonymous inner class. 
My attempts of changing the code is as follows,

```
class Combine{
    BinaryMap source;
    RectangleC area;
    Point at;
    Combine(BinaryMap bm, RectangleC rc, Point p){
        source = bm;
        area = rc;
        at = p;
    }
    void combine(int[] target, int[] source){
        final int shift =(area.X & WordMask) - (at.X & WordMask); 
        int vectorSize = (area.Width >> WordShift) + 2; 
        CombineLocals combineLocals = new CombineLocals();
        combineLocals.Vector = new int[vectorSize]; 
        combineLocals.SrcVector = new int[vectorSize]; 
        Parallel.For(0, area.Height, delegate(), combineLocals);
    }
    public CombineLocals delegate(int y, CombineLocals locals, int shift){
        LoadLine(locals.Vector, new Point(at.X, at.Y + y), area.Width); 
        source.LoadLine(locals.SrcVector, 
                  new Point(area.X, area.Y + y), area.Width); 
        if (shift >= 0) 
             ShiftLeft(locals.SrcVector, shift); 
            else 
             ShiftRight(locals.SrcVector, -shift);
        combine(locals.Vector, locals.SrcVector);
        SaveLine(locals.Vector, new Point(at.X, at.Y + y), area.Width);
        return locals;
    }
}
```

However, when I tried to call the delegate function in Parallel. For function I did not know what to put as parameters.
The original class is taken from this SDK
https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?source_dir=SecugenPlugin-master/src/sourceafis/simple/Fingerprint.java#

Comment: Why not the same as before?

Comment: The class becomes complicated when it is implemented in c++

Comment: That is out of scope for your question. Your question is `However, when I tried to call the delegate function in Parallel. For function I did not know what to put as parameters`. The answer is: the same as before

Comment: Could you kindly specify what is the same as before?

Comment: `Parallel.For(0, area.Height, delegate, combineLocals); `

Answer (score 0):

The function `Parallel.For` expects a term of type `ParallelForDelegate<CombineLocals>`.  That means you have no choice: you have to create something of type `ParallelForDelegate<CombineLocals>`.

If you don't want to use an anonymous inner class, then you need to create a named class that implements the interface.  Since this class will not be in the same scope as your original inner class, you will need to find a way of passing the appropriate values in.

```
public class CombineDelegate // Think of a better name.
implements ParallelForDelegate<CombineLocals>
{
  private final BinaryMap source;
  private final RectangleC area;
  private final Point at;
  private final CombineFunction function;

  @Override
  public CombineLocals delegate(int y, CombineLocals locals) {
    // as in your anonymous inner class
  }

  @Override
  public CombineLocals combineResults(CombineLocals result1, 
                                      CombineLocals result2) {
    // as in your anonymous inner class
  }
}
```

You will also need to include mutator methods and/or a constructor to set the values of the private fields.  Then you can implement your `Combine` method as follows.

```
void Combine(final BinaryMap source,
             final RectangleC area,
             final Point at, 
             final CombineFunction function) {
  final int shift = (area.X & WordMask) - (at.X & WordMask); 
  // etc...
  combineLocals.SrcVector = new int[vectorSize]; 

  ParallelForDelegate<CombineLocals> delegate =
    new CombineDelegate(source, area, at, function);

  Parallel.For(0, area.Height, delegate, combineLocals); 
}
```

If that's too difficult to implement in C++, then you'll need to find another way of writing the code.

**Note:** you should not call a Java method `Combine`; call it `combine` instead.